# Running Docker on a windows 2012 server virtual machine

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2012, docker, docker-for-windows

I have a windows 2012 server virtual machine, and i am trying to install and run docker on top of it, its running into all sorts of errors with Hyper-V, are there any specific steps which i have to follow?, my docker container always fails saying couldn't start MobyLinuxVM: hyper V features are not enabled.

Comment: Did you try to enable them? As for steps at least the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/) has quite a bit in relation to Hyper-V?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you need to enable Nested Virtualization.  Docker for Windows uses Hyper-V.  The only way to run Hyper-V in Hyper-V is with Windows 10 and Server 2016.
Steps for nested virtualization: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization

found this: http://blog.davidchristiansen.com/2016/11/run-hyper-v-docker-on-virtual-machine/
Confirms the nested virtualization bit.